# Is there a formula for retrieving data from multiple cells on a different spreadsheet and adding to one single cell on another spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet, vlookup

I am working on a project in which I need to retrieve the Parent Items for a list of scrap material. The problem is that most of this material is used in multiple Items. When I run a separate report to retrieve this information, I get a list of all the Parent Items the material is used in but they appear in different cells. I want to retrieve all of these Parent Items and add them into a single cell within a separate excel spreadsheet. Is there a formula I can use to do this? Below is an example of what I am working on.

I am looking to retrieve the multiple Parent items listed in column C of screenshot #2 that a part number is used in and add them to the cells in the "Where Used" column as shown in Screenshot #1.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide!

[image: Screenshot #1- Scrap Material Report]

[image: Screenshot #2- Need to retrieve all Parent Items in column C and add to "where used" column for all material in screenshot #1 report]

Comment: You added the `microsoft-excel-2010` tag, is that the version you're using? Excel 365 has a lot of new functions for this type of task.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough detail to allow a detailed answer; but generally `VLOOKUP()` is likely one of the alternative function(s) to use.

References between spreadsheets can be created by
a) having both open,
b) select a cell to contain a formula, type a single `=`,
c) switch to the other spreadsheet and click a cell to "pick a value from",
d) the first spreadsheet (cell) should now contain a reference to that cell.
e) cut and paste where you wish to use it.

*NOTE: the second / referenced spreadsheet has to be open when you use the first one.*

---

**Counting** the matching cells should be possible.
Finding the first one (VLOOKUP, or MATCH) is possible.

Getting a LIST of the matching ones into a single cell - never tried that, not seen it as a doable thing, and I cannot see that as "versatile".

**Array formulas** or functions might have been another possible way to handle it.
But these do not return a list of values into a single cell(?).

I'd say you need to create a database and then issue searches to summarize the content from there (i.e. SQL; select ... where ...)

**Pivot-tables** might have options that could be useful, but "single cell" lists are not there either.

**Beyond that;** Python with Pandas (programmable access to Excel sheets, Pivot tables and all that). Pandas has options that may be used in a manner similar to as if the Excel sheet was a database.

Comment: Hannu, Thank you for your response. I need to retrieve the "where used" items for all material listed in column C of the first screenshot. As you can see in the second screenshot, material in column A is used in multiple parent items (see column C). I need to retrieve all Parent Items from Column C , second screenshot and retrieve it to a single cell, in this case the "Where Used" column in the first screenshot for each specific material listed. For example, in the second screenshot material # 242 is used in 4 different Parent Items. Is there a formula to retrieve this to 1 cell?

Comment: Sorry. I cannot see that you have added any essential detail there, for what it is worth; I have added some words above that might help you further.